# Exchange 2007 Public Folder Post Limit

Tags: exchange-2007, public-folders

Quick points for someone =)

I get the "a rule in this public folder prevents a message this large from being posted" when trying to post a message with a large attachment.

I edited the "Prohibit post at (KB)"  value under the limit tab on the properties of the desired Public Folder to be a GB which is far larger than the message/item I am trying to post to the folder. Am I missing anything? Restarted the MS Information Store Service. This public folder is 2-3 deep from the "Default Public Folder". I shouldn't have to edit any values higher than the folder its self correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the correct value.

Public Folder Database Properties --> Limits Tab --> "Maximum item size".

Can be defined for the whole public folder database or for a single folder using the Public Folder Management Console.